# notification that was sent from parse received to Android on my computer but failed to Mobile

Tags: android

I got the codes of parse.com and I put them in my app That made with the android studio
but
notification that was sent from parse received to Android on my computer but failed to Mobile

Comment: please show more information: add your code, the mobile you are using and the error that you get.

Comment: my mobile is Huawei y600 and Samsung GALAXY S4

Answer (score 0):

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="hamid.com.fornotification" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines  below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
android:name="hamid.com.fornotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission   android:name="hamid.com.fornotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



<application
    android:name=".pushnotification"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="hamid.com.fornotification" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>







</application>
```

my application

```
package hamid.com.fornotification;

import android.app.Application;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;




/**
  * Created by hamid on 05/15/2015.
*/


public class pushnotification extends Application{
@Override
public void onCreate() {

     Parse.initialize(this,"J7Yxfv0ple96JsABa3l87ugA1BFUgfLBidch3per","wF12OKoIFLDVIfWOdaBvdQjBxMr3YZSmtcig5jQ1");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

}
```